# had started or started in perfect tense?

Tags: tense, present-perfect

This is my sentence:

> It's been 2 years since the pandemic started.

So I guess you understand what I want to say. But I'm confused if I should just use 'pandemic started' OR 'pandemic has/had started'.

I would also like to know if there's any other mistake in the sentence. Also, is it called a Perfect Tense according to English rules?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is in the perfect aspect ("it's been"). It's normal for the temporal adjunct "since the pandemic ... " to be used in the simple past tense, not the perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just "pandemic started" is correct. "has been ... since the pandemic had started" is awkward and considered incorrect because the perfect tense "it has been ... since" should use the simple past. I like to think of it as "since what specific point in time", and for a specific point in time the simple past makes the most sense.